# VBA Using Outlook to open excel not opening

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Hi Thanks for your help.

I have the follow code in Outlook 2010 & 2007:

```
Sub Openexcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceSH As Worksheet
    Dim strFile As String
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    strFile = "E:\All documents\susan\work\Excel projects\saving files to directory Clean.xls"

    Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
    Set sourceSH = sourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    sourceWB.Activate
End Sub
```

This code works the first time I use it after opening outlook but if I then close the excel file I can not use it again. I need to reopen this work book about 3 times

The Question at
[Outlook VBA open excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094624/outlook-vba-open-excel)
seen to have the same problem but I did not understand the answer.

"I got it figured out. I was opening a different workbook and then closing it before I try to open the second one and that was interfering with it. To fix this I kept the excel app open and ***reset the workbook object*** to the new workbook i wanted"

If some someone could help with the additional code that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great code found at [Excel interactions don't work after Excel file opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709539/excel-interactions-dont-work-after-excel-file-opened).

why I could not find this last week who knows.

```
Sub Openexcel()
' change
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
  Dim sourceWB As Excel.Workbook
  Dim sourceSH As Excel.Worksheet
'change
  Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
      With xlApp
      .Visible = True
      .EnableEvents = False
      '.UserControl = False
       '.DisplayAlerts = False
       '.AskToUpdateLinks = False

End With

strFile = "E:\All documents\susan\work\Excel projects\saving files to directory Clean.xls"
'change
Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
Set sourceSH = sourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet2")
sourceWB.Activate

End Sub
```

Thanks guys for all your thoughts.

Comment: Up one for solving it yourself. Also [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) which discussed various ways of how you can improve the way you work with objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the Excel Applicaton at the global scope and use it to open another workbooks. Not to create a new Excel instance for opening new files. You may find the [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219151) article helpful.

For example, declare the Application object outside the event handler:

```
Dim oXL As Excel.Application

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
```

Thus, you will be able to re-use it for closing and opening new workbooks.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, But I'm still not getting it. I have References to excel 14.0 object Library. I have place all dim statements out side the sub one at a time & all together. but fount the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709539/excel-interactions-dont-work-after-excel-file-opened.